# Divide YouTube Video into different hyperlinks?

Tags: youtube

I have a YouTube Video (which was NOT uploaded by myself) with 50 min length:
The video talks about different contents, each content starts at different time for example:
content_x starts @ 0minutes : 0Seconds
content_y starts @10minutes : 0Seconds
..etc

Now I would like to divide these contents according as hyperlink such that if i would like to watch any section, I can just click this link in the respective time (minutes & seconds).

I would prefer to do that in the description part for the YouTube video or in "About Section" so can you guide me how to do that? or any other simpler idea on how to reach different video contents in YouTube in dynamic and descriptive way?

Answer (score 0):

You can append the time you want to the end of the youtube link

Eg
`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXX#t=31m08s`

where 31m08s represents 31 minutes 8 seconds.

Similarly you can make links for the rest of the sections you want

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already know how to start video @ certain time but what I need is to write in my description: Content_1 so that when i click it, it will open the video @ the respective exact time. Think of it as a hyperlink in word document, where u can write a word that is referring to a physical URL....how can I do this? Can't I add hyperlink in YouTube Description section?

Answer (score 0):

Check this site : [www.youtubetime.com](http://youtubetime.com) it will generate a Youtube link with a specific starting time. Alternatively, tou can just write your time separated by spaces in a video's description (e.g. 
    very long description 0:00 part 1 1:00 part 2
etc... or you can write a comment with these time links and use it as an "index".
Hope that I've answered your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already know how to start video @ certain time but what I need is to write in my description: Content_1 so that when i click it, it will open the video @ the respective exact time. Think of it as a hyperlink in word document, where u can write a word that is referring to a physical URL....how can I do this? Can't I add hyperlink in YouTube Description section?

Comment: Yes you can. You just write it and on mouse hover kt becomes an hyperlink. Or you just write the time and it becomes a time url

Comment: Eg you write 1:30 in your description, with a space on the left and on the right, and it becomes a link pointing to 1:30 in your video

Answer (score 0):

Right click the video and select `Copy video URL at current time`.

Then paste it anywhere.